# Symfony template override not working

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I have a main template that includes some other templates in sub folders of the views/Frontend folder of my bundle. The bundle is used in some projects and I need to override some of the included templates. But the overriding, described in the symfony docs, doesn't work.

I use this code to include the template:

```
{{ include('@ppProfil/Frontend/parts/siegel.html.twig') }}
```

And in the bundle, thats extends the `ppProfil` bundle, I have created the template `siegel.html.twig` in the correct folder (`views/Frontend/parts/siegel.html.twig`).

I have cleared the cache, deleted the cache files, ... But it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it:

By using `{{ include('@ppProfil/Frontend/parts/siegel.html.twig') }}` instead of `{{ include('ppProfilBundle:Frontend/parts:siegel.html.twig') }}`, overriding doesn't work.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could get it to work with @ by configuring your twig namespaces: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html But, as long as it is doing what you want, then there is no need.